# On the Usefulness of AWK in a Job Setting

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I have been learning AWK in my UNIX class, which has been really fun; but I have been wondering how useful my AWK skills will be in a future job environment. It seems that text formatting is something that does not generally need to be handled on the command line in the way something like a shell script task necessarily would. Also, are potential employers going to care whether something esoteric like AWK is on my resume?

Comment: i don't think this belongs here...

Comment: FWIW, I find there are a *vast* number of things that I automate on just about every job I do, and `awk` is a vital component of that.

Comment: It's a bit like saying "I know how to use a cordless drill". It's certainly a very useful tool, but I'm not going to hire a carpenter because they put that on their resume...

Answer (score 2):

> I have been learning AWK in my UNIX class, which has been really fun;
>   but I have been wondering how useful my AWK skills will be in a future
>   job environment.

If you are expecting to work in a field related to systems administration or even software development on Unix-like platforms, knowing AWK can be incredibly useful.  It is a standard tool in many shell scripts.

> It seems that text formatting is something that does not generally need to be handled on the command line...

Well, AWK isn't really about text formatting.  It's about extracting data from text streams.

> Also, are potential employers going to care whether something esoteric like AWK is on my resume?

Not at all.  They *may* care that you are able to competently write shell scripts, but it's not something that will be called out explicitly.  It's such a basic skill that listing it on your resumé would look like padding.

Comment: On the other hand, if you list "shell script" as a skill then mentioning Awk and `sed` in this context at least signals that you know more than the mere basics. Many people indiscriminately list shell script skills when really they should be allowed nowhere near a real job involving shell scripting.